# Time remaining till next birthday javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build an app that users can select their birthday from calendar and the app shows users their age and time remaining till their next birthday in days, hours, minutes and seconds.  I'm using react-calendar and moment. Somehow I got the user age but I can't figure out how to get the remaining time. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Calendar from "react-calendar";
import moment from "moment";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
    age: null,
    timeRemaining: {
      days: 0,
      hours: 0,
      minutes: 0,
      seconds: 0
    }
  };

  onChange = date => this.setState({ date });

  handleClick = () => {
    const birthday = moment(this.state.date).toDate();
    const now = new Date();
    const currentYear = now.getFullYear();
    const birthYear = birthday.getFullYear();
    let age = currentYear - birthYear;
    if (now < new Date(birthday.setFullYear(currentYear))) {
      age = age - 1;
    }

    this.setState({ age });
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.date);
    console.log(this.state.age);

    return (
      <div>
        <Calendar
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.date}
          onClickDay={this.handleClick}
        />

        <div>{this.state.age}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What if somebody's birthday is Feb 29?  How will your code work on/after Mar 1st of this year?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is what you are looking for but with this code I can know how much months and days remain until the next birthday

```js
const birthday = new Date(1992, 5, 22);
const currentDate = new Date(Date.now());

const birthdayMonth = birthday.getMonth();
const birthdayDay = birthday.getDate();

const nextBirthday = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), birthdayMonth, birthdayDay).getTime() < currentDate.getTime()
? new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1, birthdayMonth, birthdayDay)
: new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), birthdayMonth, birthdayDay);

let remainingTime = nextBirthday.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();

const remainingMonths = Math.floor((remainingTime / 1000) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));

remainingTime -= remainingMonths * (60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1000);

const remainingDays = Math.floor((remainingTime / 1000) / (60 * 60 * 24));

console.log(`Remaining ${remainingMonths} months and ${remainingDays} days until your birthday`);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have already moment.js in use, you can use comparison methods of moment.js.

```
// your specific birthday you want to compare
const myBirthday: Moment = moment("2020/01/03");
// date of today
const today: Moment = moment();
// if birthday is in past, add one year
if (today > myBirthday) {
  myBirthday.add(1, "year");
}
// calculate duration of difference between those two days
const duration: Duration = moment.duration(myBirthday.diff(today));
// output the duration as you wish
console.log(duration.get("month"));
console.log(duration.get("days"));
```